# How do I inspect why CPU is always rising on Java app?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, server, garbage-collection, cpu

I have built a Java application, which works as a server for my multiplayer game. I see the CPU usage is always rising and drops immediately after I restart the Java application. How can I inspect what is wrong? Are there any tools? The server runs on Linux, but I can run it on Mac too for checking.

[image: clusterfuck]

Comment: That's what profiling tools are for. For example JMeter or YourKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have some unneeded Threads running.
If you don't have any, use [Java VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/) or [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) (my tools of choice) to find the source of the cpu usage.